# An optimal embedding result concerning Orlicz spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, orlicz-spaces

I am looking for the optimal embedding result $H_0^2(0,1)\hookrightarrow L_{\Phi}(0,1)$. This includes finding the largest possible [Yong function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space#Formal_definition) $\Phi(x)$ (the smallest space $L_\Phi(0,1)$) for which the embedding holds.

The classical Sobolev embedding result tells us that $H_0^2(0,1)\hookrightarrow C^{1,1/2}(0,1)$. Also, a [Trudinger's embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trudinger%27s_theorem) result ensures that $H^1_0(0,1)\hookrightarrow L_{\Psi}(0,1)$ where $\Psi(0,1)=e^{t^2}-1$.

Since we have second order derivatives, it seems reasonable to allow the function $\Phi(x)$ grows faster than $\Psi(x)$, i.e. 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\Phi(x)}{\Psi(x)} =\infty$$

but how much faster is a question here?